# Xcode 6 Interface builder subview size issue

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, frame, xcode6

I was using a xib to do some simple view layouts and noticed that the size of my subviews was incorrect in relation to the size of the view itself.

I decided the last time I tried to ask this question I may have already had too complicated of a product for people to fully understand what I was asking.

Here is a simple view:

[image]

It is exactly as I would like it to be position and exactly how I would have expected to lay itself out as shown here:

[image]

If you notice at the bottom there, I did a log of the size of the views. The log is as follows in my `viewDidLoad` lifecycle method.

```
NSLog(@"%f, %f", [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, self.blockView.bounds.size.width);
```

Why is it that the view width is in no way close to the actual width reported my the application's view size? I am trying to cast a shadow under my subview but since programmatically it thinks the view is much wider, this wont work. Also positioning any subviews programmatically in the purple view shown there will not work either since the frame does not match the expect frame.

PLEASE HELP.

thank you.

EDIT: LACK OF SLEEP LEADS TO FORGETTING LIFE CYCLES....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should log the view width in viewDidAppear.

> viewDidLoad is called after the view controller has loaded its view
>   hierarchy into memory.

By the time viewDidLoad is called, auto layout hasn't finished calculating your view position according to the constraints of the view.